# videos wont pop up when i click on the buttons

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have a 5 video's and video player with 5 different buttons.
When I click on any one of the buttons it loads the video, but if I want to watch a different one I have to reload the page and click on one.

How can I fix it so that you can click on any video button at any time and still make the videos work. I think I need to make a mouse down statement, if so how would I go about writing one. Here is my html and JavaScript:

### Html

```
<video id="myVideo" controls autoplay></video>
    <div>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo1()" onMouseUp="mouseUp1">Demo Reel</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo2()" onMouseUp="mouseUp2">Video1</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo3()" onMouseUp="mouseUp3">Video2</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo4()" onMouseUp="mouseUp4">Video3</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="addVideo5()" onMouseUp="mouseUp5">Video4</a> 
    </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var myVid = document.getElementById('myVideo');

var myVidContents1 = "<source src='video/demoreel.mp4' type='video/mp4'/> <source src='video/demoreel.webm' type='video/webm'/> <source src='video/demoreel.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>";

function addVideo1() {
    myVid.innerHTML = myVidContents1;
}

var myVidContents2 = "<source src='video/video1.mp4' type='video/mp4'/> <source src='video/video1.webm' type='video/webm'/> <source src='video/video1.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>";

function addVideo2() {
    myVid.innerHTML = myVidContents2;
}

var myVidContents3 = "<source src='video/video2.mp4' type='video/mp4'/> <source src='video/video2.webm' type='video/webm'/> <source src='video/video2.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>";

function addVideo3() {
    myVid.innerHTML = myVidContents3;
}

var myVidContents4 = "<source src='video/video3.mp4' type='video/mp4'/> <source src='video/video3.webm' type='video/webm'/> <source src='video/video3.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>";

function addVideo4() {
    myVid.innerHTML = myVidContents4;
}

var myVidContents5 = "<source src='video/video4.mp4' type='video/mp4'/> <source src='video/video4.webm' type='video/webm'/> <source src='video/video4.ogv' type='video/ogg'/>";

function addVideo5() {
    myVid.innerHTML = myVidContents5;
}
```

Comment: how about using "target=_blank"..

Comment: where would i add this in exactly?

Comment: Not relating to the problem but I would suggest creating an array with the information and then calling addVideo(id) rather than defining a new addVideo() function for each item. Anytime a block of code is completely duplicated and one little data bit changed, it's usually indicative of a problematic design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addVideo1() {
    myVid.innerHTML = myVidContents1;
    return false;
  //This over-rides the default link behaviour,
  // so the browser doesn't scroll to the top of the page instead of firing your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create the new source tags, you need to force the video element to load the new sources, like so:

```
myVid.load();
```

See:
[trying to add a multi source video player with more then one video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682586/trying-to-add-a-multi-source-video-player-with-more-then-one-video/13732056#13732056)

Your click handlers should work just fine, but there may be some strange UX side effects. You're probably better off using a tag other than "a", such as "span" or "button", and then you can set the click handler in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('link1').addEventListener('click', addVideo1, false);
// etc...
```

Don't leave off that third "false" argument, otherwise your code will break in older versions of Firefox.